# Kafka Connect not stopping on SIGTERM

Tags: java, apache-kafka, systemd, apache-kafka-connect

When systemd triggers the default kill signal (SIGTERM), Kafka Connect does not fully stop. Looking at the logs I can see the individual connector tasks and a couple of other services all say they're stopping and then report they've actually stopped, except for the "herder":

```
[2017-08-02 17:50:06,372] INFO Kafka Connect stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:68)
[2017-08-02 17:50:06,377] INFO Stopping REST server (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:154)
[2017-08-02 17:50:06,652] INFO Stopped ServerConnector@4218500f{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8083} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector:306)
[2017-08-02 17:50:06,908] INFO Stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@616fe72b{/,null,UNAVAILABLE} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler:865)
[2017-08-02 17:50:06,929] INFO REST server stopped (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:165)
[2017-08-02 17:50:06,935] INFO Herder stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder:76)
[2017-08-02 17:50:06,941] INFO Stopping task payments-kinesis-sink-0 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:341)
[2017-08-02 17:50:06,950] INFO WorkerSinkTask{id=payments-kinesis-sink-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:262)
[2017-08-02 17:50:07,025] INFO Stopping connector payments-kinesis-sink (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:218)
[2017-08-02 17:50:07,032] INFO Stopped connector payments-kinesis-sink (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:229)
[2017-08-02 17:50:07,068] INFO Worker stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:122)
[2017-08-02 17:50:07,081] INFO Stopped FileOffsetBackingStore (org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore:68)
[2017-08-02 17:50:07,082] INFO Worker stopped (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:142)
```

When this happens, the process just hangs until systemd's `TimeoutStopSec` duration is met, and then it sends a SIGKILL.

To get around the problem for now I've just lowered the timeout, however before we go into production I want to have things shutting down correctly.

I've tried looking through the source code but I can't pinpoint where it's hanging.

Is there a specific way to stop Kafka Connect?

Comment: Try taking a jstack while it's stuck. That will help debugging. It should shut down with a sigterm. What version is this?